# Wanting to find the flight departure time for an Air Canada flight AC1620 (YYZ to FLL) on Feb 28 '22 - getting a runaround by AC for a claim

Tags: airlines

Wanting to find the flight departure time for an Air Canada  flight AC1620  (YYZ to FLL) on Feb 28 '22  - getting a runaround by AC for a claim

Comment: I’d be curious to understand how the actual flight departure time may be relevant for a claim? Depending on the claim, I could see the actual arrival time, or the scheduled departure time being relevant, but the actual departure time?

Comment: Maybe the OP missed the flight, and believes the departure was earlier than scheduled.